# Is the following sentence correct -- "This brings to an end of the topic of inheritance in C++"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

> This brings to an end of the topic of inheritance in C++.

Comment: No...It doesn't make sense. The correct way of writing it is - ***"This brings an end to the topic of inheritance in C++"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Man_From_India is correct.  It should be

> This brings an end to the topic of inheritance in C++.

Your current sentence:

> This brings to an end of the topic of inheritance in C++.

makes it unclear what the object of "bring" is, because prepositional phrases qualify or modify something before them, either in the sentence or in context, and "to an end" doesn't appear to have something it points to.

"of inheritance in C++" - modifies/qualifies "of the topic"

"of the topic" - modifies/qualifies "to an end"

"to an end" - modifies .... what?

If you said:

> This brings to an end the topic of inheritance in C++

"the topic" is no longer a prepositional phrase, so it can function as *bring*'s object in the sentence.

This is also valid (and a bit more clearer in my opinion):

> This brings the topic of inheritance in C++ to an end.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging :) ***This brings to an end the topic of inheritance in C++*** and ***This brings the topic of inheritance in C++ to an end.*** are also correct, IMO. But you will find people say this - ***This will bring an end to the topic*** - more. The difference is not in the meaning. In ***This will bring an end to the topic***, ***"end"*** is being brought to ***"the topic"***, and in the other sentences ***"the topic"*** is being brought to the ***"end"***.